# Apache tomcat on AIX

Tags: apache, aix

We want to upgrade the Apache Tomcat to the latest version of AIX and Tomcat. So is there any compatibility matrix which can tell what version of Java & Apache Tomcat is supported on the AIX 7.1

Comment: Both are standalone packages. Check here [http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1022644](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1022644) what kind of java you can install on AIX and download tomcat accordingly (I think ver. 8 is most current but I'm not sure IBM docs can be a mess. Still that article was modified on:
 Modified date: 30 November 2018
so I believe its current)

Comment: So, does that mean we can install any Tomcat version on AIX 7.1?

Comment: According to this [http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) if you can install java 8 on AIX (and you can if you have 7100-03 or 6100-07 of AIX release) the answer should be YES.
If you don't have testing environment try to install java alongside existing one and test new tomcat version.